# Comunication between C program and script or cron

Tags: c, linux, cron, monitoring

We have a remote device that is controlled by a C program. This program often fails so we want to introduce some monitoring. Either the program crashes and exits or some bug happens and the program is not responding.

We want to set up a cron task or some other scripts for monitoring. What is the best modern practice for communication between C program and bash script or cron? We have access to the source code of this C program, so we can introduce some sort of error messages / events. Should they be written to a file that is later parsed by cron or some other monitoring script - or is this approach obsolete and there is some API or Linux messaging system for communication is such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple variant, use a watchdog. The program on regular intervals writes to a well-specified file. If the file haven't been updated in a long enough time, the program is unresponsive, and you should kill and restart it.

With that said, the best solution is of course to fix the problems that cause the crashes or unresponsiveness. You should have enough logging to be able to pinpoint exactly when and where things go wrong. And perhaps make sure there's a coredump available for crashes, so you can debug it.

Comment: I would have to write my own watchdog, since /dev/watchdog is system-wide, right?

Comment: @Aleksander Yes, as a plain simple function in your program that touches or writes a dummy value to a file somewhere. The monitor program then checks the last-written timestamp of the file to make sure that it's recent enough.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to have your program (written in any language) touch a specific file (i.e. create it without writing anything to it) every time it succeeds at doing its task.  Then you can have a monitoring program check the existence of the file and how recent its timestamp is.  Monit can do this easily, or you can write a shell script that does it in a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux / unix variants then you can use 'ps' command in a loop in a script to monitor whether your program is still running or not. You can use the -C option of ps.

Another method would be to write a new C program and then this C program should fork a child process which will run your original C program and then in the parent you can call wait(). wait() will return when the child process has exited. So, you will know when the child process has exited and then you can take appropriate action(s).